# Connection drops after `MacAuthEvent` times out. How can I make it more stable?

Tags: network, wifi

I am troubleshooting network connectivity issues and I found some log messages that could point to their root cause.

```
12/04/2015 15:38:03.000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: d0:2d:b3:33:a2:c6 Auth timed out
12/04/2015 15:38:06.000 kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en1   Auth result for: d0:2d:b3:33:a2:c6  MAC AUTH succeeded
12/04/2015 15:38:06.000 kernel[0]: wlEvent: en1 en1 Link UP virtIf = 0
12/04/2015 15:38:06.000 kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en1
12/04/2015 15:38:06.000 kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #2, bssid d0:2d:b3:33:a2:c6
12/04/2015 15:38:06.000 kernel[0]: en1: BSSID changed to d0:2d:b3:33:a2:c6
12/04/2015 15:38:06.000 kernel[0]: en1: channel changed to 1
12/04/2015 15:38:06.000 kernel[0]: en1::IO80211Interface::postMessage bssid changed
```

What could trigger the authorization time out? Looking at the logs I also see something weird. Apparently the *bssid* didn't change but my Mac thinks so, and it doesn't look quite right. Is there something wrong in my network setup?

Comment: you are using en1! is that on Ethernet cable , since the WiFi is normally on en0.

Comment: In my system, pretty much a vanilla installation of Yosemite, I have the Ethernet network on en0 and the WiFi network on en1. As far as I can tell I didn't change any setting to get to this configuration.

Comment: ok, looking at your log and comparing it to what I have, the first time out can happen, but it immediately tries again and succeeds. The bssid change is normal (I have it as well).  kernel[0]: MacAuthEvent en0   Auth result for: 10:c3:7b:51:2f:00  MAC AUTH succeeded...
kernel[0]: wlEvent: en0 en0 Link UP virtIf = 0...
kernel[0]: AirPort: RSN handshake complete on en0...
kernel[0]: wl0: Roamed or switched channel, reason #8, bssid 10:c3:7b:51:2f:00...
kernel[0]: en0: BSSID changed to 10:c3:7b:51:2f:00